# Making a container to distribute over all the window screen

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

I am working on a web api, in UI the container is just distributed to certain amount of browser window where there is content but I want to distribute it all over the browser regardless of the content.

**CSS**

```
.container {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-top:70px;
    *zoom: 1;
    border:none;
    background-color:aliceblue;
    }
```

**Screen Shot**

In the below screenshot it can be seen that the lightblue(aliceblue) is just distributed upto some extent and remaining was grey. I would like it all aliceblue

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simply adding "height: 100%" to your css?

Comment: You will also need to add `html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }` and here is a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/GVuEy/1/.

Comment: No problem, best of luck in your design.

Answer (score 0):

Add height: 100%; to your container and it should be fine

Comment: That alone is not working, adding html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; } is working